# How to compile libdash on MAC OSX for the target iOS

Tags: mpeg-dash

I'm working on DASH-MPEG streaming technique, and find out the open source library which help me accomplish the function. ( https://github.com/bitmovin/libdash )

It told that the library is across-platform available. And I'm trying to apply it for iOS platform. But I get stuck on compile the library source on MACOS.

Because I have no idea on cmakefile ,  Could you help create the makefile to bypass this problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: So, did you find an answer?
Were you able to stream DASH from an iOS device?